# Can JavaScript running within a PDF access the domain it was downloaded from?

Tags: javascript, security, pdf

This is a security question. Say User A is logged into example.com, and he then downloads a PDF hosted by example.com which he views within the browser. Is JavaScript embedded within the PDF able to access example.com's APIs as if it were the logged in User A?

Or stated differently, do API calls originating from JavaScript within a PDF get sent to the server with the session cookie that the browser may be holding for that domain?

Comment: Im pretty sure that you can not have javascript in a pdf that gets executed.  A PDF document is just that a documeht, javascript can dynimacally create a save a pdf..

Comment: You can run JavaScript in a PDF. The documentation is here: http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf

Comment: What APIs are you interested in using? How does a PDF keep track of the domain from which it was downloaded? If I download a PDF and then re-host it on my own server, the file won't change.

Comment: I don't expect the PDF to be able to track the domain from which it was downloaded. However, if you click a PDF on the web it will open within your browser, with the domain it was downloaded from appearing in the browser's URL bar. My question is for a PDF running in such a state, do API calls from within the PDF's JavaScript make their way to the server with whatever preexisting session cookie the browser had been holding for that domain?

Comment: Also, I am not interested in using any APIs within a PDF. I'm trying to figure out whether a security concern exists with hosting user-generated PDFs directly from my application's domain.

Comment: Browsers and official Adobe PDF viewer uses totally different code bases. For example Firefox uses https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/ which is totally different than Adobe PDF application . Probably only Adobe PDF client supports that embedded Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few URL-related commands in Acrobat JavaScript. There is also the path information which can be retrieved.

The URL-related commands are (list maybe not complete) `getURL()`, `launchURL()`, and `submitForm()` . They all can essentially send data to any server, as long as that server can do something with the data. It does not matter whether the PDF is viewed in the browser or not. This can indeed be a security issue.

However, for several versions already, at least the Adobe products have a barrier built in, which either completely bans, or requests permission to contact another server than where the document comes from. That means, that it is quite difficult to do something behind the provider's and the user's backs.

Answer (score 0):

They can interact, but only via the [`HostContainer`](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/acrobat_sdk/9/Acrobat9_HTMLHelp/JS_API_AcroJS.88.776.html#1954541) object.

> This object manages communication between a PDF document and a
>   corresponding host container that the document is contained within,
>   such as an HTML page. The host container for a document is specified
>   by the Doc hostContainer property. The Embedded PDF object provides
>   the corresponding API for the object model of the container
>   application.

The `HostContainer` is limited to the `postMessage` method for communications with the hosting page:

> Sends a message asynchronously to the message handler for the host
>   container of the PDF document. For this message to be delivered, the
>   host container (for example, an  element in an HTML page) must
>   have registered for notification by setting its messageHandler
>   property. The message is passed to the onMessage method of the
>   messageHandler.

So it does not have full access to the DOM like an HTML document does. It is more like a document loaded from another, or a `null` origin (dynamically created document in an IFrame) which can use the HTML5 `postMessage` functionality to communicate with its parent frame in a safe manner.

There is also the `submitForm` method mentioned in the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/acrobat_sdk/10/Acrobat10_HTMLHelp/JS_API_AcroJS.88.532.html).

> Submits the form to a specified URL. To call this method, you must be
>   running inside a web browser or have the Acrobat Web Capture plug-in
>   installed.

It is not clear whether cookies are included in the request or not, or whether the `referer` header is set or not. If both are true then an CSRF attack could be accomplished if the site is using `referer` checking as the defense mechanism.

Comment: The quote about submitForm() is either very old, or incomplete. The kind of current Acrobat JavaScript documentation continues with "Beginning with
Adobe Reader 6.0, you need not be inside a web browser to call this method."

Comment: @MaxWyss: Link updated, thanks. Just wondered, did you have a security related point there, or were you agreeing? Thanks.

Comment: The security-related point is that submitForm() no longer needs to have either webCapture active and/or requires running under a browser; it can therefore live without hostContainer.

Comment: @MaxWyss: Yes it can. However, I'm not going to assume that it won't use its host if it exists with the possibility of also sending its host's cookies.